# EJBCA WSDL Port mismatch

Tags: wildfly, ejbca

When installing ejbca 8.0 using
OS: RHEL 9
AppServer: WildFly 26
using standard installation when running it throws wrong port on wsdl (expected: 8443, got: 8080)
where can i change the port?

```xml
<wsdl:service name="EjbcaWSService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:EjbcaWSServiceSoapBinding" name="EjbcaWSPort">
<soap:address location="https://localhost:8080/ejbca/ejbcaws/ejbcaws"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Following the official EJBCA documentation but wsdl port mismatch in RHEL 9

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on GitHub, but add it here as well for reference.
This is the wsdl-host configuration of the wildfly setup in:
https://doc.primekey.com/ejbca/ejbca-installation/application-servers/wildfly-26#WildFly26-HTTPProtocolBehaviorConfiguration